# Automatic case transformation for events in vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I have a Vue3 component that emits multiple events. I want to pass the callbacks in a dedicated callback object like this:

```
// template section 

<!-- emits event-a and event-b in kebap-case -->
<my-component v-on="myCallbacks" />


// script section

const myCallbacks={
  'event-a': function() {  // kebap-case does *not* work
   ...
  },
  
  eventA: function() {    // camel-case works !
    ...
  },

  eventB: function() { 
    ...
  }
}
```

The [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#event-names) state that in Vue3, unlike in Vue2, there is an automatic event name transformation (apparently into kebap-case).

Why can't I use the expected kebap-case in the callback?
Did I miss a more appropriate design pattern that could replace such a callback object and is still concise?
Is this name transformation on a callback object standard behavior or subject to change? Is it documented somewhere?

I hardly found anything in the docs about using `v-on` without the event specifier (i.e. `v-on="callback"` instead of `v-on:event-a="eventA" v-on:event-b="eventB"`).

// **Update**
In the [Vue2 doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on) and [Vue3 doc](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/directives.html#v-on), they mention that this is called the "object syntax" - however, nothing is written about case transformation.

```html
<!-- object syntax (2.4.0+) -->
<button v-on="{ mousedown: doThis, mouseup: doThat }"></button>
```

Comment: I think you mean this @eventName="callback" i.e., @event-a="eventA"

Comment: I meant that `v-on="callback"` should call a generic callback object which processes all callbacks, that is, has a callback function for every expected event (e.g. specified by `emits`) - in contrast to having to specify every callback for every event explicitly.

Comment: Ohh so you mean you want a generic callback with a generic event just for easy coding in template right?? Hmm good question. Let me think

Comment: Check this resource https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947747/how-to-listen-to-all-custom-events-in-vuejs here a person asked for a global event handler for all events for log purposes. If we can use this and create an Event Bus to listen to all types of events then I think we can have what We want

Comment: It's actually more about a syntatic sugar version, similar to what they do in vuetify (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702245/vuetify-tooltips-what-are-on-and-attrs-for).
I'm aware of that eventbus pattern, which does not work anymore in Vue3; in Vue3 you have to use an explicit event bus like mitt (https://github.com/developit/mitt)

Comment: Ohh I see. So this `mitt` will give u what u want I guess

Comment: I know how to use a generic event handler - this is not my problem. I just wonder that the case transformation on Vue's built-in generic event handling mechanism, which they call the "object syntax" in the `v-on` directive, is hardly documented, and partially misleading in that one might assume that events are converted into kebap-case, whereas the opposite seems to be true for the callback object provided to the "object syntax" variant of `v-on`.

Comment: Hmm I see your point. That's why I don't use it like that. Simply :attr="value" and @event="callback" saves the day and make the code more readable for me.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question before but now or seems clear

Comment: Thank you for your effort anyways :)